# Put the whole playlist of youtube video urls into an array using JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I'm trying to put the videos from a playlist to an array. I want to create my little custom playlist on a website, and I need only the URLs. Do I have to go through 40 videos and pick them by hand, or is there an option to do it more efficiently and longer lasting?

I already made it work on an array that's hard coded into the app.js file. I'm providing the link so you can see what I'm going for.

https://vast-atoll-28054.herokuapp.com/video.php#inVideoPage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of youtube api to do so. Check [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems). You will not have to pick manually.